# Cluster analysis for multi-response question

Tags: clustering

Let's say I have check-all-that-apply survey question.  What kind of analysis can I run to understand if there are meaningful clusters (i.e. there's a cluster of people who choose A, B, C, and another cluster that choose A, D and E)?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. If there are people who chose A and B then they will show up in clusters choosing (A,B,C) and (A,B,D). What sort of clusters are you particularly interested in?

Comment: Multiple response data are data of binary variables. There exist a lot of proximity metrics for such data (Jaccard being among the most popular). You base your clustering on the matrix of such distances.

Answer (score 1):

Two key approaches:

- Consider the options to be binary, and use an appropriate distance measure such as **Jaccard similarity**, which he developed for biological research: "check all species that live in this region". Then you have a wide variety of clustering algorithms available.
- Use **frequent itemset mining**, and check if you have interesting frequent patterns. The benefit is that these patterns *may* overlap, and can be transformed to rules such as "users that chose A and B also picked C in 90% of the cases".

Comment: Can you recommend a source to read about frequent itemset mining, including its algorithm, so that one may want to try to code it oneself?

Comment: That should be covered in every data mining book. Apriori is the most known data mining algorithm (and it's one of the top 10 important data mining algorithms: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10115-007-0114-2 ). Although I'd rather use FPGrowth which is more clever (but also more complicated).