# How to cluster individuals based on a set of variables with multiple responses?

Tags: clustering, survey, multiple-response

I collected data on foods that people avoid and the reasons why they do so via a questionnaire.

Here is an overview of the data:

```
  participants  eggs   alcohol              meat
1           p1  <NA>      <NA>              <NA>
2           p2 vegan      <NA>             vegan
3           p3 vegan  religion vegan & regligion
4           p4  <NA> donotlike              <NA>
```

As you can see, each person can potentially avoid no (participant 1), one (participant 4), or multiple foods (participants 2 and 3). Also, each food can be avoided for one or multiple reasons (f.ex. participant 3 doesn’t eat meat because he is vegan but also because of his religion).

For my research, **my goal is to find patterns in these data that would coherently group people who avoid the same foods for the same reasons**. 
Ideally, I would like participants 2 and 3 to have a high degree of similarity, because they both avoid eggs and meats as vegans. But I would also like participant 3 to be close to other participants who only avoid alcohol and meat because of their religion but who are not vegan.

I am familiar with multivariate exploratory techniques and clustering but it is the first time that I have to deal with variables that can take multiple responses (say the variable meat can take both the value „vegan“ and „religion“).
I have found other [posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116028/cluster-analysis-for-multi-response-question) asking somewhat similar questions but I could not find how to apply the advice to my problem.

**How would you approach this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

You probably only have a few different responses, each several times.

There won't be much statistical support for grouping them any different than by identity. A single difference makes each record potentially completely different.